# Sending extra parameters in UIButton instance

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uikit

Is it possible to send **extra parameters** when I instantiate this button class, like so:?

```
BttClass *myButton = [[BttClass alloc] init];
```

If so, what is the correct syntax? I have been trying all sorts!
**I would like to send a BOOL and a string.**
Thanks.

Comment: My first question is why? If you are following the `MVC` principles you should not need to add any extra info to view, these should be in your model. Just my thought on the subject.

Comment: Maybe the button needs (okay maybe not need but 'wants') to be clever enough to change it's title and it uses these parameters to do so?

Comment: Damo is right, I am making a custom button. The regular custom options won't do, because of the design. (Admittedly, maybe UIButton isn't the right choice for me though. Perhaps I should use UIControl, or something else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend UIButton by subclassing it.

```
//MyButton.h
@interface MyButton : UIButton {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* aString;
@property (nonatomic, weak) BOOL aBool;
```

You need to define an initialiser method

```
-(id)initWithStringValue:(NSString *)stringValue andWithBoolValue:(bool)boolValue;
```

Then implement the initialiser method

```
//MyButton.m
-(id)initWithStringValue:(NSString *)stringValue andWithBoolValue:(bool)boolValue {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.aString = stringValue;
        self.aBool = boolValue;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In a calling class your code would look like

```
MyButton* myButton = [[MyButton alloc] initWithStringValue:@"tralala" andWithBoolValue:YES];
```

Comment: If it helped then mark up/Accepting answer always appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just define a custom initializer and pass in your values:

```
- (id)initWithBoolValue:(bool)boolValue stringValue:(NSString *)stringValue  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks melsam. Needed to know how to call it too though. (Answered by Damo below.)

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom button

in your

CustomButton.h

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton

    - (id)initWithBooleanValue:(BOOL)value;

@end
```

and in your 
CustomButton.m

```
- (id)initWithBooleanValue:(BOOL)value
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bool = %d",value);
    }
    return self;
}
```

You can use this class in place of your normal UIButton

Comment: Thanks Aatish. Needed to know how to call it too though. (As answered by Damo.)